# Retrieve json array on ajax success and loop json array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

I'm getting and json array on ajax success. I just encode it on my controller class and then get it on success.
Here is my json

```
var info = {
    "full_name" : "Ray Villalobos",
    "title" : "Staff Author",
    "links" : [
       {
            "blog"     : "http://example.com",
            "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/example",
            "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/example",
            "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/example",
            "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/example" 
       },
       {
            "blog"     : "http://example.com",
            "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/example",
            "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/example",
            "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/example",
            "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/example" 
        },
        {
            "blog"     : "http://example.com",
            "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/example",
            "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/example",
            "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/example",
            "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/example" 
        }
    ]
};
```

right now, I'm retrieving the key and values like this if my link has only one dataset instead of an array:

```
for ( key in info.links ) {
    if (info.links.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    output += '<li>' +
    '<a href = "' + info.links[key] + '">' + key + '</a>' + '</li>';
   } //if the links has the key property
} // for...go through each link
```

how do I retrieve array key,values in my loop?

Comment: have you try **foreach( $arrayValue as $key => $value)**

Comment: replace all info.links to info.links[0]   hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get what I expected. Here's the code:

```
var output = "";
var linksCount = info.links;

for (var counter = 0; counter < linksCount.length; counter++) {
    for ( key in infolink[counter]) {
        if (infolink[counter].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            output += '<li>' +
            '<a href = "' + infolink[key][counter] + '">' + key[counter] + '</a>' + '</li>';                            
        } //if the links has the key property
    } // for...go through each link
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but in a "for ... in" loop, the key here is the index of the array. You can obtain the link using this code:

```
var link = info.links[key];
```

And then retrieve the relevant properties, in your case, the properties could be "link.blog" or "link.facebook" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (infolink in info.links){
 for ( key in infolink ) {
  if (infolink.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   output += '<li>' +
   '<a href = "' + infolink[key] + '">' + key + '</a>' + '</li>';
  } //if the links has the key property
 } // for...go through each link
}
```

Comment: I tried this. but in here it only get first array of links array. I want to retrieve all array data in links array.

Answer (score 0):

here the elements of array info.links are not array. the value of info.links are objects so you can not retrieve 'blog/facebook/youtube' like that. the output of the key will '0/1/2'

so you can try this

```
    for(var key in info.links){
        document.write('<li><a href="'+info.links[key].blog+'">Blog</a></li>');
        document.write('<li><a href="'+info.links[key].facebook+'">Facebook</a></li>');
        document.write('<li><a href="'+info.links[key].youtube+'">YouTube</a></li>');
        document.write('<li><a href="'+info.links[key].podcast+'">Podcast</a></li>');
        document.write('<li><a href="'+info.links[key].twitter+'">twitter</a></li>');
        document.write('<hr/>');
}
```